# How can I add mini search for sub-categories?

Tags: magento-1.9, search

My Store has some Categories and sub-categories as :
-- Default Category
    
     -- Pass-over
        
          -- EP5
        
          -- EP15
    
     -- Self-serve
        
          -- EP02
        
          -- EP99
In my mini search form, It Shows Pass-over, Self-serve in Category search

I want EP5, EP15 ni category search,
My form.mini.phtml code for mini search is :

```
<div class="mid_part_bg_img">
    <form id="search_mini_form" action="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getResultUrl() ?>" method="get">

        <div class="form-search">
        <?php
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
    if(is_object(Mage::registry('current_category'))){
        $currentCategoryPath=Mage::registry('current_category')->getPathIds();
    }else{
        $currentCategoryPath = array();
    }
    $category->load(Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
    $childrenString = $category->getChildren();
    $children = explode(',',$childrenString);
    $categoryOptions='';
    foreach($children as $c){
        if($this->getRequest()->getParam('cat')==""){
            $selected = (in_array($c, $currentCategoryPath))?'SELECTED':'';
        }else{
            $selected = ($this->getRequest()->getParam('cat')==$c)?'SELECTED':'';
    }
    $categoryOptions.= '<option value="' . $c . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $category->load($c)->getName() . '</option>' . "\n";
    }
?>

           <select name="cat" id="cat">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <?php echo $categoryOptions ?>
</select>
            <input id="search" type="text" name="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getQueryParamName() ?>" value="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getEscapedQueryText() ?>" class="input-text"  maxlength="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getMaxQueryLength();?>" />

            <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Search')) ?>" class="button search_btn"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
            <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
                var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', '<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->jsQuoteEscape($this->__('Search entire store here...')) ?>');
                searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete');
            //]]>
            </script>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add below function in your helper

```
function get_categories()
{
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category'); 
    $treeModel = $category->getTreeModel(); 
    $treeModel->load();

    $ids = $treeModel->getCollection()->getAllIds(); 

    $data = array();

    if (!empty($ids))
    { 
        foreach ($ids as $id)
        { 
            $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category'); 
            $cat->load($id); 
            $categoryData = array('id'=>$cat->getId(),
                              'url'=>$cat->getUrl(),
                              'name'=>$cat->getName(),
                              'image'=>$cat->getImageUrl(),
                              'isActive'=>$cat->getIsActive()
                             );
            if($id>2)
            {
                array_push($data, $categoryData);
            } 
        } 
    }

    return $data;
}
```

in `form.mini.phtml` include below code into form

```
<select id="category" class="search_select" name="cat">
     <option value="">category</option>
     <?php 
     $categories = Mage::helper('<your_module>')->get_categories();
     #echo '<pre/>';print_r($categories);exit;
     foreach($categories as $k=>$v) 
     {
     ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $v['id']; ?>" <?php echo  (isset($_GET['cat']) && isset($_GET['q']) && $_GET['cat'] == $v['id'] )? 'selected':''; ?>><?php echo $v['name']; ?></option>
     <?php 
     } 
     ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: instead of not working will you say what exactly you are getting. First make sure you are getting array return fron your module @Himani.VC

Comment: working great  :)